# Can you create a google calendar event description template that you fill out when creating a new event

Tags: calendar

i am new to script so bare with me please. We use google calendar in the workplace to create customer appointments. multiple people over multiple computers create appointments.There are 2 google accounts that are linked. is it possible to make a event description template that you fill out every time you create a new event? Like customer name:  customer phone # ...
Thank you in advance for taking time to help.

i have been play around but cannot seem to get anything to work
const calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
calendar.setDescription('Updated calendar description.')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.